# (#100)the parameter object is required

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-interface

```
    Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
    postParams.putString("fb:app_id", "234256810031533");
    postParams.putString("name", "test app");
    postParams.putByteArray("picture", MainActivity.byteArray); 
    postParams.putString("og:type", "place");
    postParams.putString("place:location:latitude", "90");
    postParams.putString("place:location:longitude", "45");
    postParams.putString("access_token", pageaccessToken);
    /* make the API call */


    Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
            if (error != null) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                         error.getErrorMessage(),
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            else {
                JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject()
                        .getInnerJSONObject();
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                String postId = null;
                try {
                    postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
                }

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Successfully Shared", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            }
            finish();
        }
    };

    Request request = new Request(session, "/me/objects/place", postParams, 
                          HttpMethod.POST, callback);

    RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
    task.execute();
```

I am using Facebook SDK 3.7 and i got error "(#100)the parameter object is required". How can I post a place with photo using longitude and latitude. I can not understand please help me. I am using `/me/object/place` to post place with picture.

Answer (score -2):

this works for me.

```
FB.api('/me/objects/[namespace]:place',
'post', {
"access_token" : FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'],
object: {'url': 'test',
type': '[namespace]:place',
'title': 'test',
'image': 'test'
}
},function (response) {
console.log(response);
if (!response || response.error) {
alert('Error occured');
}
}
);
```

Comment: Good for you, why do you think a javascript solution to post an image to someone's timeline is applicable to someone having a problem posting coordinates attached to a photo via the Android SDK? What question were you attempting to answer?